# How use call a local server by name rather than IP?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, networking, web-server

I've started [MAMP](http://mamp.info) on my computer and I'd like to make a GET call from Android app. I'd like to access the computer by it's name(e.g. computer.local:8888) rather than the computer's ip.

On the computer if I open Chrome and type `computer.local:8888` it works as expected. On the phone this fails, but typing it's local ip (`192.168.1.141`) works.

So, is it possible to access a local http server by a name rather than ip ?
If so, how ?

Comment: Programming questions should be asked in StackOverflow.com

Comment: @geffchang I don't think this is really a programming question. It could just as easily be about accessing a local web server in the browser, or using a local network video stream in a video player.

Comment: @geffchang just rephrased, same thing, different way of  accessing

Comment: Looks completely on-topic to me (same explanation as Dan above). Forget about the development-related section: that's not the issue George has, but only serves to give some background for better understanding. He would have the very same trouble with all other examples Dan described -- and no development would be involved.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings→Network*, tap *WiFi*, and watch out for your WiFi AP here. Tap it, select to edit it. Toggle the "advanced settings" to be shown.

By default, WiFi is configured via DHCP -- but for some reason unknown to me (and escaping my understanding), Android doesn't pick the *name servers* via DHCP, and instead sticks to Google's hardcoded ones (e.g. `8.8.8.8`). So in this place, you need to switch to a static IP, set the default gateway correspondingly, and put your own name server's address (most likely again your router's IP) into the field for *DNS1*.

Save the changes, and you should be able to use your local hostnames. You could even try switching back to DHCP, and see whether it keeps your *DNS1* settings.

To calm down upcoming worries: This only affects the WiFi AP you edited, no system-wide changes for all WiFi APs. In the worst case, you always can delete the AP and re-create it.